# ANZ goMoney AU not alllowing developer options to be enabled

Tags: developer-options

I have recently purchased a Nexus 6, to install **Kali NetHunter**.

After installing **ANZ goMoney AU**, It opens, and prompts me with:

> We noticed that you have some Developer Options turned on under your Settings.
>
> This can cause issues with ANZ goMoney.
>
> To continue, please turn them off and restart the app.
>
> <kbd>EXIT</kbd>

I was wondering if there was any way to bypass this screen, as I use developer options for a lot of things.